# where the error messages will be inserted when the errors that they represent occur

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having an issue figuring out how to write the following code:
the problem is that I'm using an empty `<div>` with the id error-display. This `<div>` is where the error messages will be inserted when the errors that they represent occur. I want to make all fields validated when the user clicks off of them to the next field. If there’s an error, an error message should be displayed. Likewise, error messages should be removed when the user fixes the problem. yet I'm not sure how to do it! here is what I got so far:

```
    <div id="error-display">
  </div>
    <form id="project-form">
        <br>E-mail:<span class="error">* </span>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Example@example.com" required>
        <br>Password:<span class="error">* </span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"  id="password" required>
        <br>Confirm Password:<span class="error">* </span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"  id="password-confirmation"  required>
```

After inserting the emipty "div id="error-display">" what can I do?
lets say the error message is: Invalid email address.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Example@example.com" required>
```

I tried "required" in the input elements and it's working for my inputs, however, I think my professor is looking for a different solution.

Comment: Read up on how to use html5 form validity with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add `change` event listener for every input field and to validate each of them and if some are invalid you should set `innerText` property of the 'error-display' div to error message text

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and simple solution for you

in all of your input fields, put `onchange="validateField(fieldID, fieldname)"` like this

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onchange="validateField('email', 'Email')"  placeholder="Example@example.com" required>
```

then paste this script below your form (or you can have this in a separate js file)

```
<script>
   function validateField(fieldID, fieldname) {
     var inpObj = document.getElementById(fieldID);
       if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
         document.getElementById("error-display").innerHTML = "Invalid " + fieldname + ":" + inpObj.validationMessage;
       } else {
         //this will clear your error if the input is already correct
         document.getElementById("error-display").innerHTML = "";
       } 
   }
</script>
```